# iOS Safari iFrame content height keeps increasing when resizing absolute element height to window.innerHeight

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile, mobile-safari

window.innerHeight keeps increasing every time I try to resize absolute element(s) to window.innerHeight.

JSBin (open using a real iOS Safari device or XCode's simulator) -
https://jsbin.com/qivupe

This strange behaviour does not reproduce when the page is not iframed and only occurs on iOS mobile Safari. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. The bin you sent requires a pro account to be edited
2. There is no code in your post that will help us help you
3. You probably have some paddings/margins that are applied after you size the element so there is a new innerHeight every time you do it.